# Superharmonic functions and amenability

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, random-walks, amenability

Let $G$ be a group generated by a finite set $S$. Let $P$ be a Markov operator defined by the uniform measure on $S$. A function is superharmonic if $Pf\leq f$.

Assume that there is a set of non-negative superharmonic functions $X$, which satisfies

(1) $X$ is convex and invariant under $P$

(2) There exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $G$ such that
 $f(g.x_n)/f(x_n)\rightarrow 1$ for all g in $G$.

What are the conditions on this set one can impose in order to conclude amenability of the group? If the set of all non-negative superharmonic functions satisfies (2) then the paper "Amenability and superharmonic functions" by Northshield [1] implies amenability. It seems one should be able to read more information provided extra conditions on this set. I would be interested to have any citation on related articles.

[1] 
*Northshield, S.*, [**Amenability and superharmonic functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2159941), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 119, No.2, 561-566 (1993). [ZBL0785.31006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0785.31006).

Comment: I suspect you mean $G$ rather than $P$ in condition (1).

Comment: I mean $P$. It also seems that it should be the same to ask.